# Does adding an partition in windows harm linux partitions?

Tags: partitioning, windows, gparted

I have a dualboot of windows 7 and ubuntu. Now I want to add an extra partition in windows with the internal partition manager. But does this hold any danger for the existing linux partitions? I mean, can this do any harm to my linux partitions in a way that it is wiped or something like that? Or should I use another program like gparted?

Also, when doing this via windows, do I only need to shrink the first partition and then add an additional one?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it does not. So just go a head.

Modern distributions use UUID´s to detect what partition to mount where. So its not dependent of the partition scheme.

But yes in the old days adding a partition would mean you changed names for partitions possibly rendering your system unbootable until you changed the partition names to be correct in your fstab file

Comment: +1 for mentioning the old naming convention in `/etc/fstab`. Basically it does not matter _which_ OS changes the partitioning scheme. The only important aspect is the OSs should find the partitions required to boot/run the system.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can make no harm. But keep in mind that under windows you can manage ntfs and fat32 partitions only.